# CreateObjectURL memory leak in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, memory-leaks

I'm developing a web application which everyone can edit image on the internet directly.

While developing the site, I have faced a big problem with opening local system files.

Typically, we can do that with two ways as already known like below.

First, to use `FileReader`.

```
// render the image in our view
function renderImage(file) {

  // generate a new FileReader object
  var reader = new FileReader();

  // inject an image with the src url
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    the_url = event.target.result
    $('#some_container_div').html("<img src='" + the_url + "' />")
  }

  // when the file is read it triggers the onload event above.
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

// handle input changes
$("#the-file-input").change(function() {
    console.log(this.files)

    // grab the first image in the FileList object and pass it to the function
    renderImage(this.files[0])
});
```

second, to use createObjectURL and revokeObjectURL.

```
   window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);

function handleFiles(files) {
  if (!files.length) {
    fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
  } else {
    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    fileList.appendChild(list);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      list.appendChild(li);

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
      img.height = 60;
      img.onload = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
      li.appendChild(img);
      var info = document.createElement("span");
      info.innerHTML = files[i].name + ": " + files[i].size + " bytes";
      li.appendChild(info);
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, both of them do not work well in Chrome browser. (IE is fine)
I could open the local files by using both of them. But also, those always made memory leaking even though I exactly called `revokeObjectURL` when I used second way.

I have already checked that the blobs are released well from `chrome://blob-internals/`. All of blob had released well. But, Chrome had still hold physical memory and the memory was not released forever unless I refresh the page.  Eventually, Chrome was crashed when the memory usage was up to 1.5GB.

`FileReader` showed me the same resulting although I released refs. Besides, the way showed terrible I/O performance.

http://ecobyte.com/tmp/chromecrash-1a.html (by logidelic)

Here is a test page. You can test this problem with just drop files onto the green DOM. The testing page is using `createObjectURL`/`revokeObjectURL` method.

When you do this testing, you could see the physical memory consumption from task manager (Shift + ESC) or your own OS task manager.

Did I miss something or is it a bug as already known?

Please, somebody help me! If you know another way to resolve this, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the createObjectURL method. In the end, I find that the memory can be released by adding the code in the onload function:

```
this.src = '';
```

However, the image will disappear from the web page, as you may expect.
In addition, I also notice that sometimes the chrome (50.0.2661.102) or chrome canary (52.0.2740.0) fails to release the memory even with this.src= ''. Once it happens, you need to restart chrome. Simply refresh the page doesn't work.

I have tried the readAsDataURL method, too. The memory can be released well (even as the chrome fails to release memory for createObjectURL with this.src=''.) However, the drawback is that the speed is rather slow (around 10x longer as compared to createObjectURL).